# Bold letters inside excerpt

Tags: theme-development, excerpt

I'm currently trying to get some of the words that are inside an excerpt to be bold with "h1" tag but it does not seem to be working. When I checked online, all that I come ac cross was the suggestion to use a plug in. Is there a way to achieve this without a plugin. My CSS looks as shown below.

```
.side-bar h1 {
    font-weight: bold!important;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You may already know this, but the `<b>` or `<strong>` tags are better choices if all you want to achieve is bold text. `<h1>` should be reserved for the most important header(s) on your page.
2. By default, WordPress strips out a lot of what's in excerpts, including images and HTML tags. To undo this, you'll need to create or edit your theme's `functions.php` file. Either of these links will give you a description of how to write/edit `functions.php` to achieve this and other changes to the excerpt:

   - http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-preserve-html-tags-in-wordpress-excerpt-without-a-plugin/
   - http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/improving-wordpress-the_excerpt/